# Revised version of Task Defination in AWSCLI

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

From AWS console when i push image in ECR i create a new version of task definition with latest image and then update the service with new version of task definition (for ECS fargate cluster)

Now i want to do same from AWSCLI.For that i am using below command.Here  TD-DC.json is exactly same json which i get when i go to console create new version of taskdeination ----> Configure via json

```
 aws ecs register-task-definition  --family API-servie-fetch --cli-input-json file://TD-DC.json

 Parameter validation failed:
 Invalid type for parameter ipcMode, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 
 'str'>
  Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].logConfiguration.secretOptions, value: None, 
 type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].linuxParameters, value: None, type: <class 
'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].resourceRequirements, value: None, type: <class 
'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].ulimits, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, 
 valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].workingDirectory, value: None, type: <class 
 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].secrets, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, 
 valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].memory, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, 
 valid types: <class 'int'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].memoryReservation, value: None, type: <class 
 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'int'>
  Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].stopTimeout, value: None, type: <class 
  'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'int'>
  Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].startTimeout, value: None, type: <class 
 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'int'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].firelensConfiguration, value: None, type: <class 
 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].dependsOn, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, 
valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].disableNetworking, value: None, type: <class 
'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'bool'>
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].interactive, value: None, type: <class 
'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'bool'>
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].healthCheck, value: None, type: <class 
'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].hostname, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, 
valid types: <class 'str'>
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].extraHosts, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, 
valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].pseudoTerminal, value: None, type: <class 
'NoneType'>, 
valid types: <class 'bool'>
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].user, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid 
 types: <class 'str'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].readonlyRootFilesystem, value: None, type: <class 
'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'bool'>
 Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].privileged, value: None, type: <class 
'NoneType'>, 
 valid types: <class 'bool'>
  Invalid type for parameter pidMode, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 
 'str'>
  Invalid type for parameter proxyConfiguration, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: 
  <class 'dict'>
```

Why i am not able to create new version of task definition ?

Comment: Can you share the contents/format of `file://TD-DC.json`? Based on the error I'd say it's having an issue with reading the field values from your json config

Comment: @tanvi to create a revised version of task definition from awscli from where shall i take json ?